# Do we always get Full table scan while inserting a new row

Tags: mysql, sql

When we insert a new row in the DB, does it always do a full table scan in MySQL
as I think since all the columns are inserted newly,
there will be no use of any index as such

explain plan looks something like this:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "insert": true,
      "table_name": "my_table",
      "access_type": "ALL"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, there will be no full table scan when you insert a row in the table. Why should the DBMS read the table, when all there is to do is add that row? That wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: bit confused , what does "access_type": "ALL" mean here . if there is no FTS

Comment: I suppose that access_type just doesn't apply. As no data is read from the table, there is no access, hence no access_type.